# смена размера textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Как изменить количество колонн в textarea для определенного размера экрана? (в моем случае "@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 970px)") . Просто при данном размере поле выходит за границы блока, нужно уменьшить кол-во колонн. Как можно это реализовать при помощи JavaScript? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> нужно уменьшить кол-во колонн

Не нужно.

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

Comment: Действительно, помогло. Не знал об этом, глупый совсем) Спасибо!

Comment: @Getrix2020, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочки слева от него.